# Idea - better have all items in form or adding them there one after second?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, forms

I wonder about situation, if is better to have all of posible items in form, or if is better  to add the item to form in a moment, when the user want it.

I will try to explain it a bit more - I have form with 4 inputs and one textarea. And then I have an offer of optionals values (ca 15 - it's 15 numbers).
And now I am thinking, if is better load these 15 numbers and add them to form as **display: none;** and if the user will want some of these items, so I will change CSS (to **display: block**) and the items will be in form.

Or the second possibility - if the user will want to add some of these items, so with using AJAX I will add it to form.

I think the second option is cleaner, the first one simpler => and I want to use the first one, but... what will be faster? (I guess the AJAX version - the first version - I will not is so slow?)

What you think about it?

Comment: 15 numbers is no concern to anything performance based so if you already have the numbers, add them and dont display them (your first option). The extra requirement for an AJAX call to fetch 15 numbers doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: AJAX usually means fetching some data from the server, did you simply mean "javascript" instead?

Comment: @Wesley no, I did AJAX. If the user will click on the link "I want add the value A", so then will be AJAX call to database, I will get the item from database and displayed it.

Comment: @Wesley and the case without AJAX - I would have everything loaded and if the user did click to link "I want add the value A", so I will just call the JS function for displaying it (JS function should set the value of input from **display: none** to **display: block**)

Comment: OK, yeah I don't quite understand what you're doing. I just can't visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing to consider here.

- If you want the user interaction to be responsive then load it up with the page.
- If you are going to start getting elaborate (as in start adding some complex functionality beyond what you have stated) then maybe Ajax is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking 'which is more usable', make a quick prototype and get a few people to use your different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should only load data from ajax (JSON), not HTML, because you can do the rendering with JS and it will be faster and cause less server load.

If there are always just those 15 optional values anyways then why not just put them in HTML straight away. Or is fetching them taking too long in your server? Since we cannot know how bad load it will cause its hard to say what is correct. If you have to fetch separate data for every optional value to have in form then Ajax is ofcourse better since you wont then have to do useless load for the optional fields. But if the optional form fields do not even require extra queries and you could do them anyways straight away then ofcourse then it would be better.